# How can i get browser url detail from node in ubuntu and windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu-14.04, node-webkit

i am making an desktop app for which i need it to detect browser url .Suppose i am running google chrome with www.stackoverflow.com then it should give me the url www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: This is something low-level. I'm not sure whether you'd be able to use nodejs for this. You might be able to write something that monitors the 'chrome' process and access its url, but that's not something you'd really want to do in javascript. That program could pass a value or two to nodejs, but, again, that's an OS thing.

Comment: That is what is my requirement . I have done it for MAC by apple script and i am able to run applescript by node but how to do for ubuntu and windows .

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is sites visited then (in the case of Chrome) you can constantly read and extract visited URL’s from the file http-cache (? I think) under…

```
…AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

And maybe other browsers have something similar.